# Pass either with list or with

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to pass the first arguments of `do.calc` either independently or with a list, but when I pass a list into `...` I don't see it inside `calc`. This is not a problem when I call `calc` directly rather than in `optim`. Am I missing something about how `optim` works?

```
do.calc <- function(...){
  optim(x, calc, ...)
  return(NULL)
}

calc <- function(x, ...){
  args <- list(...)
  if(is.null(names(args))) {args <- unlist(args, rec = F)}  # my attempt at handling the optional list
  args <- c(args, other = 3)
  dput(args)
  return(0)
}

do.calc(list(a = 1, b = 2))

do.calc(a = 1, b = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `do.call` and pass the argument to the function `do.calc` as a `list`

```
do.call(do.calc, list(a = 1, b = 2))
```

-testing

```
out1 <- capture.output(do.call(do.calc, list(a = 1, b = 2)))
out2 <- capture.output(do.calc(a = 1, b = 2))
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or another option is `invoke` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
invoke(do.calc, list(a = 1, b = 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

akrun's answer gave me a good lead but didn't quite answer my question because doesn't leave me the option of passing arguments both as `list` and independently. Trick is to do the argument-handling earlier before passing to `optim` -- I think because optim needs its `...` arguments to be named.

```
do.calc <- function(...){
  args <- list(...)
  if(is.null(names(args))) {args <- unlist(args, rec = F)}
  optim(x, args=args)
  return(NULL)
}

calc <- function(x, args){
  args <- c(args, other = 3)
  dput(args)
  return(0)
}

do.calc(list(a = 1, b = 2))

do.calc(a = 1, b = 2)
```